# NSTextField non-system-font content clipped when usesSingleLineMode is true

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

Setting usesSingleLineMode to true for a non-system font causes the top of the text to be clipped.

I've created 3 very simple test cases that illustrate this:

- *good* : non-system font, with usesSingleLineMode = false. Works fine.
- *bad* : non-system font with usesSingleLineMode = true. Does not work.
- *system* : system font with usesSingleLineMode = true. Works fine.

Add the following to the viewDidLoad() method of a new Cocoa OSX application:

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
let good = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 55))
good.usesSingleLineMode = false
good.font = NSFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 24)
good.stringValue = "Good usesSingleLineMode false "
self.view.addSubview(good)

let bad = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 800, height: 55))
bad.usesSingleLineMode = true
bad.font = NSFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 24)
bad.stringValue = "Bad usesSingleLineMode true"
self.view.addSubview(bad)

let system = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 800, height: 55))
system.usesSingleLineMode = true
system.font = NSFont.systemFontOfSize(24)
system.stringValue = "Good usesSingleLineMode true, System Font"
self.view.addSubview(system)
```

[image: See the result]

If I create the same `bad` NSTextField using Interface Builder in a storyboard, set the font in IB and check Uses Single Line Mode in IB it works fine! But, it would be impractical to build the overall view in IB, thus I want to programmatically create it.

Why is this happening? Have I missed some important setting (I've tried adjusting many NSTextField and NSTextFieldCell parameters to no avail? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Strange, I have a button with a custom font as well, but when I set `UsesSingleLineMode = true`, the text remains in its normal place.

Comment: "Cells in single-line mode use the fixed baseline layout. The text baseline position is determined solely by the control size regardless of content font style or size." source: [usesSingleLineMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSCell/usesSingleLineMode)

Comment: Willeke, I did manage to overlook that, so I appreciate you pointing it out. However, this is clearly not the whole story. If I replace HelveticaNeue-UltraLight with just HelveticaNeue (which is the same as the system font), the text is still clipped. Whereas if I use NSFont.systemFontOfSize(24) there is no clipping. Also, all control sizes are identical, so one would conclude the baselines would be identical.

Comment: I am curious to know if you tried various fonts to see if that had any effect.

Comment: Did you try setting the font before setting usesSingleLineMode?

Comment: I have tried various fonts and tried different orders of setting parameters, including usesSingleLineMode=true after/before everything else.

Comment: @drootang I have the same thing happening. Have you managed to fix this?

Comment: @invisible_hand Nope, never figured out how to replicate the results completely programatically. Using IB and storyboards.

Comment: Seeing the same issue. As a workaround I'm setting: `textField.maximumNumberOfLines = 1` and `textField.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail`

Comment: I'm seeing this same thing when entering emoji in my `NSTextfield`. Screenshot: https://d.pr/i/2tUeGc If anyone ever figures this out, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple themselves, this is correct and even desired behavior:

> Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended based
>   on the following information:
>
> This behaves correctly according to the documentation for NSCell:
>
> Cells in the single line mode use the fixed baseline layout. The text
>   baseline position is determined solely by the control size regardless
>   of content font style or size.

Source: http://www.openradar.me/13813516

What the documentation says is really correct but the important detail here is what the documentation does not say. It does say that the "*text baseline position is determined solely by the control size*" but it does not explain in detail how this is done. And it is a known fact, that the baseline always seems to fit correctly to the system font, yet it hardly ever fits to any other font on your system. The problem is that Apple speaks of "***the*** fixed baseline layout", as if that would be something known and well documented, but it isn't. I haven't found any document, not even among the legacy ones, that would explain **the** fixed baseline layout.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Apple's response

Answer (score -1):

I solved it the problem by setting `usesSingleLineMode` to `false`.

Comment: `usesSingleLineMode` is `false` by default but the solution to "How do I use that mode correctly?" cannot be "Don't use it". The OP is setting this on purpose as it will also trigger specific behavior that your text views won't have, so this is not an  answer at all, the OP is very well aware that the problem won't occur that way, he even posted a screenshot which exactly demonstrates it; hence downvote.

Comment: Thank you! it helped and to block multiline you can just use `controlTextDidChange` delegate method to replace new line characters: `stringValue = String(stringValue.filter { !$0.isNewline })`