# How to change the height of a NSTextField?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

I am trying to change the height of a `NSTextField` for a macOS application.

How can I change the height of my `NSTextField` and have the text centered vertically like a normal `UITextField` on iOS. I added a height constraint to try and make it bigger and nothing will change.

```
class LoginVC: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailField: TF!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: STF!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    emailField.usesSingleLineMode = true
    emailField.placeholderAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Email", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.lightGray, NSFontAttributeName: NSFont(name: "Menlo", size: 20)!])
    emailField.alignment = .center

    passwordField.usesSingleLineMode = true
    passwordField.placeholderAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.lightGray, NSFontAttributeName: NSFont(name: "Menlo", size: 20)!])
    passwordField.alignment = .center
}

override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    view.layer?.backgroundColor = EYE_GREY.cgColor
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you want set an attributed string with a font size of 20.0 to a text field?  I find your work very underdeveloped.

Comment: Why don't you set the font in the storyboard? This will automatically resize the height of the text field.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but the reason why your layout is broken is because you use `usesSingleLineMode` with a font other than the system font. Either don't set this mode (even if you just want a single line of text, you can enforce that by other means if you have to) or use the system font. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49784243/15809